laptop monitor not working after install of nvidia-550
I m running ubuntu 20.04 dual boot on an asus rog x13 with nvidia 4070.
until now I was using the proprietary 535 and things were kind of working but I couldn't get it to detect any external monitors.
I downloaded and installed the nvidia-550 from the nvidia website and did not work. Now the external monitor works fine via the HDMI port but the laptop monitor is NOT working. Went back to the recommended 535 and the problem persists. The only way to get the laptop monitor to work is to use the x.org.x nouveau driver.
I already tried the apt remove --purge nvidia* and reinstall but the problem persists.
I would like at the very minimum to be able to use the laptop monitor and I would like to not have to reinstall Ubuntu.

Use the Nvidia drivers offered by the Canonical repositories or graphics-drivers PPA if you need a more experimental version.  Be more thorough in your purges -- dpkg -l |grep -i nvidia and sudo apt purge them all.  Then sudo apt install nvidia-driver-xxx and reboot. Note, the standard driver install methods (ubuntu-drivers, Software&Updates) are in flux on later releases, not sure about 20.04, but if the driver packages are available, they can be installed.
